# C# - OpenGl.Net shaders fail to compile with no errors

Tags: c#, opengl

I am using C# and OpenGL.Net to make a simple program to display a triangle, but for some reason the program runs and leaves the screen blank. It says that both the vertex and fragment shaders failed to compile, but there is no error list.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text;

using SFML;
using SFML.Graphics;
using SFML.Window;
using OpenGL;

using System.Media;
using System.IO;

namespace SFML_Test
{
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            // Create the main window
            ContextSettings settings = new ContextSettings
            {
                DepthBits = 24,
                StencilBits = 8,
                AntialiasingLevel = 2 // optional
            };
            RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Works!");
            window.Closed += new EventHandler(OnClose);

            Color windowColor = new Color(0, 0, 0);
            // Setup
            uint vao = Gl.GenVertexArray();
            Gl.BindVertexArray(vao);

            float[] trianglePoints = 
                { -0.5F, -0.5F,
                0.5F, -0.5F,
                0F, 0.5F};
            uint vbo = Gl.GenBuffer();
            Gl.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            Gl.BufferData(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, (uint)(4*trianglePoints.Length), trianglePoints, BufferUsage.StaticDraw);
            SetupVertexShader();

            Gl.EnableVertexAttribArray(0);
            Gl.BindBuffer(BufferTarget.ArrayBuffer, vbo);
            Gl.VertexAttribPointer(0, 3, VertexAttribType.Float, false, 0, (IntPtr)0);
            Gl.DrawArrays(OpenGL.PrimitiveType.Triangles, 0, 3);
            // Start the game loop
            while (window.IsOpen())
            {
                window.DispatchEvents();
                window.Clear(windowColor);
                Gl.DrawElements(OpenGL.PrimitiveType.Triangles, 3, DrawElementsType.UnsignedInt, 0);

                Thread.Sleep((1/30) * 1000);
                window.Display();
            }
        }
        static void SetupVertexShader()
        {
            uint vertexShader = Gl.CreateShader(ShaderType.VertexShader);
            string[] shaderString = File.ReadAllLines(@".\Shaders\vertex.shader");
            Gl.ShaderSource(vertexShader, shaderString);
            Gl.CompileShader(vertexShader);
            int success;
            Gl.GetShader(vertexShader, ShaderParameterName.CompileStatus, out success);
            if (success != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vertex Creation Success.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Vertex creation fail.");
                Gl.GetShader(vertexShader, ShaderParameterName.InfoLogLength, out int logLength);
                int logMaxLength = 1024;
                StringBuilder infoLog = new StringBuilder(logMaxLength);
                Gl.GetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024, out int infoLogLength, infoLog);
                Console.WriteLine("Errors: \n{0}", infoLog.ToString());
            }
            uint fragmentShader = Gl.CreateShader(ShaderType.FragmentShader);
            Gl.ShaderSource(fragmentShader, File.ReadAllLines(@".\Shaders\fragment.shader"));
            Gl.CompileShader(fragmentShader);
            Gl.GetShader(fragmentShader, ShaderParameterName.CompileStatus, out success);
            if (success != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fragment Creation Success.");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Fragment creation fail.");
                Gl.GetShader(fragmentShader, ShaderParameterName.InfoLogLength, out int logLength);
                int logMaxLength = 1024;
                StringBuilder infoLog = new StringBuilder(logMaxLength);
                Gl.GetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 1024, out int infoLogLength, infoLog);
                Console.WriteLine("Errors: \n{0}", infoLog);
            }
            uint shaderProgram = Gl.CreateProgram();
            Gl.AttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
            Gl.AttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
            Gl.BindFragDataLocation(shaderProgram, 0, "outColor");
            Gl.LinkProgram(shaderProgram);
            Gl.UseProgram(shaderProgram);
        }
        static void OnClose(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Close window
            RenderWindow window = (RenderWindow)sender;
            window.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is vertex.shader:

```
#version 150 core

in vec2 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

And here is fragment.shader:

```
#version 150 core
out vec4 outColor;
void main()
{
    outColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

**EDIT:**
As suggested by [Luca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/161554/luca) (Thank you) I added Gl.Initialize() before everything 
else. I also removed `core` from the preprocessor directive, and now the shaders compile with this error:

```
WARNING: 2:1: invalid profile specified
ERROR: 2:1: '' : syntax error: #version
ERROR: 2:1: '' : syntax error: unexpected tokens following preprocessor 
directive - expected a newline
```

Any help?

Comment: Maybe calling Gl.Initialize before everything could solve your issue.

Comment: This is another issue, but you should ensure that *each* line in the array of strings representing the source really, really, ends with a \n character.

Answer (score 1):

Your shaders begin with `#version 150 core`, which match an OpenGL 3.2 Core Profile version.

To have it properly you must set the proper context.

I don't know SMFL. Looking into its [sources](https://github.com/SFML/SFML.Net) I can guess something about your issue, you lack this context setting. You should do something like this:

```
    // Create the main window
    ContextSettings settings = new ContextSettings
    {
        DepthBits = 24,
        StencilBits = 8,
        AntialiasingLevel = 2, // optional
        MajorVersion = 3, // OpenGL version
        MinorVersion = 2, // OpenGL version
        AttributeFlags = ContextSettings.Attribute.Core
    };
    RenderWindow window = new RenderWindow(new VideoMode(800, 600), "SFML Works!", settings);
    window.setActive(true); //set the context as current
```

Another way is to let SFML asks for a *Compatibility Profile*, which is opposite with a *Core Profile*. Then start your shaders without "core", like 
`#version 150`

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but the `ContextSettings` constructor does not appear to contain an option for `AttributeFlags`.

Comment: [It is](https://github.com/SFML/SFML.Net/blob/2.3/src/Window/ContextSettings.cs) since SFML 2.3.

Comment: SMFL.Net doesn't support version 2.3 yet.